# Class arguments vs constructor arguments

Tags: python, class, object, oop, constructor

So my original question was I don't understand why you would have a class argument i.e. `class Animal(animal_being)` but then I realized that it is probably for when you want to do inheritance.

So if someone confirm that I understood it correctly, that'd be great. Because initially I was confused why you'd have class arguments when you can have all the arguments you want in the constructor/__init__ method.

Though if I am correct, do you need self as an argument in the class like the `__init__` method or not?

Comment: The official python tutorial on [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) is helpful.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. In a class definition, the arguments, are base classes so it's related to inheritance. All methods, including `__init__()` are automatically passed a `self` argument which is the class instance. In Python, `__init__()` is an *initializer*, not a constructor (that's `__new__()`).

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out a way to mark martineau's comment as the answer (given that the other response was essentially a link), so I'm answering my question by saying that his comment is the answer to my question.